# Deny windows pop-up error messages with batch or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am working on a way to start a program via a network drive.(Example follows). Is there a way to suppress these error messages from Windows via Batch or Powershell while the script is running? Or maybe a way to dynamically search for the Network drive without trying all possible ways.

Code Exapmple:

```
@echo off
start A:"Path to .exe" 2>nul
B...
C...
// For every possible drive letter
```

Comment: You could use Win32_LogicalDisk and select only those with a Network Drive Type from both Batch and PowerShell. Try searching, using those terms, we're not here to do it all for you.

Comment: I just needed some input cause i cant find anything on the net. Thanks.

Comment: What error messages? The question does not contain any examples. As @Compo said, you can iterate over a list of network drives. It is easier in PowerShell IMO. Then, if the '\path to .exe" exists, you want to run it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily get all successfully connected network drives with the `net use` command. Put a `for /f` loop around to get the drive letters only:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('net use^|findstr /b "OK"') do (
  start "" "%%a\path to .exe\app.exe"
)
```